# How do I get div not to display if value in another div is empty in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, visibility

Here is my code. I have tried everything I can think of. I have tried using just div ID's and have now tried classes. Nothing seems to work. I just want the number 2 not to be visible if there is no entry beside it. It doesn't matter if it is in a table or not.

Thanks.

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.leftone {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
.rightone {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
.lefttwo {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
.righttwo {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
-->
</style>


<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" id="tableONE">
    <tr>
        <td width="200" height="50"><div class="leftone">1.)</div></td>
        <td width="200" height="50"><div class="rightone">The Number One</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="200" height="50"><div class="lefttwo">2.)</div></td>
        <td width="200" height="50"><div class="righttwo"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function shownumbers() {
    var myNum1 = '[.rightone]';
    if(myNum1 != ''){ 
        document.getElementById('.leftone').style.display = "block"; 
    }
    else if(myNum1 == ''){ 
        document.getElementById('.leftone').style.display = "none"; 
    }
    var myNum2 = '[.righttwo]';
    if(myNum2 != ''){ 
        document.getElementById('.lefttwo').style.display = "block"; 
    }
    else if(myNum2 == ''){ 
        document.getElementById('.lefttwo').style.display = "none"; 
    }
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: You are using `document.getElementById()` but you do not have any id's defined, you have class names defined.

Comment: You're using CSS classes as ID's. You should have a shared class or just a common selector ("td div" would probably work) which all have the same float, width, and height. Then you can use IDs if you really need them to hook into your JS.

Comment: This makes no sense? What triggers the function, and how can a variable be empty if you set it to a string on the line above ?

Comment: Try using this `style="display:none;"`.  You can mix that with JS to determine when to show/hide it (`if(document.getElementById("myElem").style.display=="")document.getElementById("myElem").style.display="none"; else document.getElementById("myElem").style.display="";`)

Comment: You should use a shared class to identify all the "left" parts as a collection, then iterate through them. For each one, traverse the dom for the contents you need (.next will probably come in handy) and see if they're empty (=== "" should be sufficient). Then show or hide the entire row. If you want to stop the iterator as soon as a blank is encountered, you can just get out of the loop.

Comment: Thanks guys. Of course you are right I screwed up trying it with classes - should have stuck with IDs only and I accidentally took out the onload function to fire it. So I took the function part out but it should still work and doesn't. David - I am not quite sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use getElementById with classes. Also, you don't need the '.' or '#' when using these methods in javascript. Below should do what you are asking. Although if there is only ever 1 item of class 'rightone' and 'leftone' you should use ID's.

```
var myNum1 = document.getElementsByClassName('rightone')[0].innerHTML;
if(myNum1 != ''){
    document.getElementsByClassName('leftone')[0].style.display = 'block';
} else if(myNum1 == ''){
    document.getElementsByClassName('leftone')[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

A more elegant solution would be:

HTML:

```
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" id="tableONE">
    <tr>
        <td><div class="left">1.)</div></td>
        <td><div class="right">The Number One</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="left">2.)</div></td>
        <td><div class="right"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var right = document.getElementsByClassName('right');

for(var i=0;i<right.length;i++){
    if(!right[i].innerHTML){
        right[i].parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('left')[0].style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        right[i].parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('left')[0].style.display = 'right';
    }
}
```

Comment: I realized too late that I screwed up the class and ID's in my code, Sorry. I didn't realize that I should use the innerHTML tag. Got it all to work perfectly now. Thank you very much for your help to all of you guys. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda similar to Jason's, but I spent the time so I'mma post it. ;)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H3UNH/1/

HTML:

```
<table id="tableONE">
    <tr>
        <td width=50>1.)</td>
        <td >The Number One</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2.)</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(I do still like the width attribute for cells in tables; it can be moved to CSS but this is one of those exceptions for me where the markup and presentation can have a tiny bit of overlap. Move everything else to CSS. Your mileage may vary.)

CSS:

```css
td { padding: 3px; text-align:left; height: 50px;}
```

JavaScript:

```
function shownumbers() {
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for(var i=0,len=rows.length;i<len;i++) {
        var _this = rows[i];
        var rowCells = _this.getElementsByTagName('td');
        if(rowCells[1].innerHTML == "") {
            _this.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

shownumbers();
```

(for the purpose of the demo, I just separately call shownumbers. If you want it to be automatic, make it self-invoking. Otherwise call it from wherever it makes sense)

I think the more important lesson here isn't the JavaScript, actually. ;) I understand that not everyone is writing perfect JavaScript (heck, mine's not perfect either). But you really need to understand the purpose of CSS and classes in general to write good maintainable markup and presentation for the web! I hope that doesn't sound too condescending or anything; it wasn't meant to be.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I had actually just thrown together this code for a test and am using it in a much bigger project with numerous html files. I do usually use separate css files, etc. but I sure screwed up the classes and the div ID when I switched over in the middle of my tests. Oops sorry about that everyone. I was actually only using IDs for the most part so each cell was separate. I haven't tried your code yet but plan to because it is always better to have more solutions than less to a problem. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Cool beans. You can play around with it in the fiddle until it's where you need it to be. For example, the function is getting ALL <tr> elements; you might want to make that particular selector more customizable for only particular tables or whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

By using the :empty selector.

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('td div:empty'),
    i = els.length,
    el;

for(;i--; ) {
    el = els[i];

    do {
        el = el.parentNode;
    } while ( el.nodeName != 'TR' )

    el.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uAUt8/

Comment: Pretty clever! I'm undecided on if it's crossing the "too clever" line (like ternary operators do) but I definitely appreciate the approach: I thought mine was pretty generic, but this is even more so (and I mean that in the good way).

Comment: I don't know. But my question is, if the table cells are empty why are they even be there?

Comment: If it's a requirement for the cells to be empty, this is the right way to mark it up. I don't know enough about the requirements to judge. ;) If the whole row becomes "useless", cosmetically hiding it is probably only the second-best plan... there might be a better way to just not render the row at all.

Comment: Yes, of course. But by "they" in "why are they even there" I mean the <tr>. If there's no data no need to create that extra table row.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. Cosmetically hiding it is probably only the second-best plan. Better to not render it at all. Sometimes APIs return data beyond our control, but *if* we can control it, not rendering is the better choice.

Comment: And that's that. I agree =P